# After Mavericks upgrade problems with PHPStorm

Tags: mac-osx, java, lag, ide

I upgraded to Mac OS Mavericks and since then my PHPStorm caused problems. During typing inside the editor the CPU goes up to 400% and the typing lags. I didn't know what to do or what the reason is. So I reinstalled Mavericks. On a clean installation PHPStorm worked fine, without lags. I then put back all my data on my SSD (from backup and only personal data, no java or system binaries). I don't know if this is the reason, but PHPStorm now again lags if I type into the editor.

Have you experienced similar behaviour? Any suggestions what to look for? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.stumiller.me/fixing-phpstorm-osx-mavericks-update/) comes up in a Google search for [“PHPStorm Mavericks”](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=PHPStorm%20Mavericks&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

> The issue is that OSX Mavericks doesn’t come with Java 6 installed,
>   which is what PHPStorm requires to run. To fix it, go here and install
>   the official Java package for OSX. After install, PHP Storm will work
>   again.

The solution appears to be installing or upgrading Java 6. Official Apple download [is here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).